# Is it possible to recover Chrome bookmarks without synching option?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

Firstly, I am NOT technical. My Macbook Air was just stolen and I realize I hadn't "synched" my Chrome bookmarks on old mac. I'm in process of restoring files from external hard drive to my new
mac.
Is there any way I can retrieve my Bookmarks? I'm rather desperate as I used them for my business.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I thought Chrome synced automatically so long as you're signed in. In future, consider two things - 1] Safari will always sync via iCloud without needing any 3rd party login procedure & 2] You really *really* should invest in a proper backup strategy; at minimum Time Machine. If it's for a business, then you should consider three copies of any data to be *absolute* minimum safety. One in-house, one off-site & one online. Your livelihood depends on it.